# How to execute a powershell script from robot framework file?

Tags: python, powershell, robotframework

I need to execute a .ps1 script from my robot framework file. I am trying process library I think it is for python. Is there anyway else to directly execute PS Script.

My Code->

```
   *** Test Cases ***
   Testcase1
    [Tags]      test
    ${KEYWORDS}=    Powershell.exe    ${CURDIR}\\test.ps1
    Run Keywords     ${KEYWORDS}
    log to console  after ps cmd
```

Error
      No keyword with name 'Powershell.exe C:\Users\test.ps1' found.

Comment: I see you edited the question to fix the code, but that's confusing for users (like me) who come after because the accepted answer makes no sense until you realize the code was fixed.

I'd suggest instead to add at the end of the question something like "EDIT : this is the fixed version : <fixed code here>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot uses two or more spaces to separate arguments from keywords. You need at least two spaces after `Powershell.exe`.

You should also use a forward slash instead of a backwards slash in the filename, or use a double-backwards-slash since a single slash is an escape character.

Comment: Thanks!! it helped

Answer (score 0):

It worked. the command is

```
  run process       Powershell.exe     ${CURDIR}\\test1.ps1
```